# Trim whitespaces in .jsx files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type in HTML in `.html` and hit save, all unnecessary white spaces are removed.

I would like to have this exact same option when I have html in `.jsx` files

This is what I tried, and have in my settings:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
  },
```

But I am not able to get this to work.

Can it be achieved this way, without another extension?

Here's an example of a `.jsx` that won't be formatted:

```
const UserDescription = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    // {/* What */ }
    <    div className='mt-20'>
      <    button className=''>Edit</button   >
```

...